# What @property declaration is best to hold a singleton class

Tags: objective-c

I need to create a reference in once of my classes to another singleton class I have.

So I declare as shown below in my interface:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) AudioStreamer *radioStreamer;
```

And later on grab an instance of the class like so :

```
self.radioStreamer = [AudioStreamer sharedManager];
```

Is using `weak` the best way to do this? I've no problems with the app and it all works as expected but I'm not sure if it is best practice when using a singleton.

Should I be using a property at all or would using an ivar make more sense.

Anybody able to advise on the best way to treat a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your singletons are never destroyed, then a `weak` certainly works. If it can be destroyed, you may want to use `strong`. Much of this will depend on context. `weak` has less meaning for singletons that never get released.

I would say stick to the generalized best practices for `weak`/`strong`. The singleton, for effective purposes, becomes just an instance of that class, albeit the singular instance you reference.

For example if you are using `radioStreamer` as a means of convenience (as well as not getting encountering the overhead of the `sharedInstance` lookup, `strong` is probably the spirit of what you want.